# Перенос слова по буквам на следующую строку, если не помещается в ширину

Tags: html, css

При переносе слов в ссылке, ее блок превышает необходимую длину справа.
Как можно убрать этот отступ так, чтобы ширина сама варьировалась в зависимости от длины слов?

Сейчас получается так, что эта ссылка с названием осуществляет перенос на новую строку, при этом заполняя полностью всю ширину, а так как фиксированной ширины нет, она заполняет сколько может.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.vacancy-item-title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="vacancy-item-title">Врач-косметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог</a>
```

Comment: Мне важно поведение именно при переносе строки! inline, flex и всевозможные комбинации в этом русле работают одинаково, оставляя справа огромное место при переносе

Comment: Вообще, я читала об этом вчера весь вечер и так понимаю, что браузер не воспринимает текст-ссылку, как блок внутри которого много элементов. И типо для него это как одна буква, а то, что я прописала в ней перенос - касается только длины блока, а ширина остается прежней. (немного примитивно объяснила, может и не права на самом деле)

Comment: может будет понятнее, зачем мне это. Я хочу справа от этого блока разместить еще один блок, но там появляется огромный отступ при переносе и выглядит неправильно. Когда название помещается в одну строку, рядом блок выглядит хорошо, но при переносе ссылка растягивается на максимальную ширину

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача решается, через `word-break:break-all;`.

```css
.vacancy-item-title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="vacancy-item-title">Врач-косметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог/Дермотокосметолог</a>
```

Если я конечно же, правильно понял вашу задачу.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.vacancy-item-title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class='vacancy-item-title'>Врач-косметолог/Дерматокосметолог</a>
```

Comment: inline тут тоже не работает. Попробуйте добавить к этому названию еще одно длинее по ширине и увидите, что слово перенесется, а ссылка займет всю строку, а не только ту область, где слова

Comment: Мне важно, чтобы при переносе строки, она обрезала ту область, что пустая. Я, честно говоря, уже все испробовала, не уверена, что это возможно, но может кто сталкивался