# Как в CSS переносить cтроки посимвольно?

Tags: css

Есть длинная строка:

```
w(N$&_MUX#eJ=H2]IKi0:*d!1a)Dr`,6;Wzk^C/EPbcOv4G{Q5LAZ7R?mYV8
```

Как при уменьшении ширины блока строку переносить посимвольно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса? [Перенос слова по буквам на следующую строку, если не помещается в ширину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049142/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для переноса по буквам, используется свойство `word-break` с значением `break-all`.

```css
span{word-break:break-all;}
```

```html
<span>
    w(N$&_MUX#eJ=H2]IKi0:*d!1a)Dr`,6;Wzk^C/EPbcOv4G{Q5LAZ7R?mYV8 w(N$&_MUX#eJ=H2]IKi0:*d!1a)Dr`,6;Wzk^C/EPbcOv4G{Q5LAZ7R?mYV8 w(N$&_MUX#eJ=H2]IKi0:*d!1a)Dr`,6;Wzk^C/EPbcOv4G{Q5LAZ7R?mYV8 w(N$&_MUX#eJ=H2]IKi0:*d!1a)Dr`,6;Wzk^C/EPbcOv4G{Q5LAZ7R?mYV8
</span>
```